How to determine share to bitcoin ratio for Bitcoin ETFs?
How do you find the share-to-bitcoin ratio of a given spot Bitcoin ETF?  I'm assuming the ratio is fixed - was fixed at the time the fund was created.  Correct me if I'm wrong!  It must be published somewhere, but where?

I'm assuming the ratio is fixed - why are you assuming that? That's not how funds work.

ok.  then how does a bitcoin ETF work?  When I buy one share, and it is backed by bitcoin, what am I actually getting?  I had thought - I thought reasonably - that for that share they actually buy some new bitcoin.

This question is similar to: How exactly does a broad-market ETF work?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You could divide the unit price of the ETF by the price of one bitcoin on the same day and see how constant it is. Since ETFs charge a fee you should see a slight decrease in the value ratio over time. You will also see a change if the ETF pays dividends (which reduces the ETF's price). So I would not expect the ratio to be constant over time.
In general, these price of these ETFs (like broad market ETFs) are often not comparable to anything else directly (e.g. the price an S&P 500 ETF does not directly reflect the level of the S&P 500 index). It will be the return (change in price) that is intended to match the return of something (bitcoin in this case). So if Bitcoin goes up 10%, you should expect the ETF to also go up 10% (minus the fees and dividends).
Keep in mind that the return is not guaranteed, though.  You do bear some risk that the return of the ETF will not exactly match the return of bitcoin. Some ETFs may have better tracking error than others, but you won't know that until you actually experience a tracking difference.

When I buy one share, and it is backed by bitcoin, what am I actually getting?

You are buying a unit of the ETF, which is owned by many other investors, and itself owns assets. I would presume it owns bitcoin in most case, but some may also one bitcoin derivatives.
It certainly does NOT mean that owning 1 unit of the ETF entitles you to a particular amount of bitcoin.
The value of that unit is based on your share of the total assets of the ETF. IF the ETF owns $1.4 billion in bitcoin and has 100 million units outstanding, then one unit is worth $14. As the price of bitcoin changes, the value of a unit changes.

I had thought ... that for that share they actually buy some new bitcoin

Not necessarily - you may be buying a unit from someone else that is selling theirs, so the fund does not need to buy any more bitcoin. Depending on the the demand for new units in the ETF, they might buy some more bitcoin, but not every transaction results in buying/selling bitcoin.
